SwiperJs thumbnails can be scrolled to outside slides
I have a swiperjs component with thumbnails at the bottom. To be able to fit as many as can fit on a page, I have limited the width and height of the swiper-slide and the contained image in the thumbnail.
The problem is, the thumbnail swiper allows scroll beyond the last thumbnail page.
Following is a pen to illustrate the issue.
https://codepen.io/ydubey/pen/KKOwYbQ
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    swiper-slide img {
      display: sw </swiper-slidek;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    body {
      background: #000;
      color: #000;
    }

    swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    swiper-slide {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
    }

    .mySwiper {
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .mySwiper2 {
      height: 20%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .mySwiper2 swiper-slide {
      width: 4rem !important;
      height: 4rem !important;
      img {
        object-fit: contain;
        width: 4rem;
        max-height: 4rem;
      }
      opacity: 0.4;
    }

    .mySwiper2 .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    swiper-slide img {
      display: sw </swiper-slidek;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <swiper-container style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="mySwiper"
    thumbs-swiper=".mySwiper2" loop="true" space-between="10" navigation="true">
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

  <swiper-container class="mySwiper2" space-between="10"
    watch-slides-progress="true">
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>
      <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>


Based on @marcelofrieres suggestions, and trial and error, this is what seems to work:

Initialize the slides-per-view to a very high number on the html, eg 1000

update slides-per-view based on the screen width and thumbnail size. 2 + 1.5 because, 1 px space between + 1.5rem to px conversion.
ngAfterViewInit() {
const swiperEl = document.querySelector('swiper-container.thumbnail-swiper');
const width = screen.width;
const remToPxFactor = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
const slidesPerView = Math.floor(width / (2 + 1.5 * remToPxFactor));
swiperEl!.setAttribute('slides-per-view', String(slidesPerView));
}



@Yougesh, did my answer below help you? I put an example as snippet and on Codesandbox too

You can initialize the Swiper by JavaScript and add the number of slides on the property slidesPerView.
You can see the example below run by clicking on Run code snippet, and you can see it too on CodeSandbox.


const listOfSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.mySwiper .swiper-slide')
    
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: listOfSlides.length,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});

var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", { 
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiper,
  },
});
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.mySwiper2 {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mySwiper {
  height: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.mySwiper .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>
  <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




I cant squeeze all thumbnails on the same page, so need the thumbnail swiper to be horizontally scrollable. If you resize https://codepen.io/ydubey/pen/KKOwYbQ, you'll see the thumbnail swiper is infinitely scrollable, rather than stopping on the last page of thumbnails.

setting slides-per-view="10" seem to have improve the extent bottom slide is allowed to be scrolled. Unfortunately, setting the value dynamically like [slides-per-view]="images.length",  doesnt seem to have the same behavior. The swiperjs documentation gives a hint as to how to change the value in code. swiperEl.setAttribute('slides-per-view', '3'); I'll give it a try.

I can update the slides-per-view via js, and that works. It turns out, I'll have to calc the number of slides my screen can fit dynamically and set the slides-per-view to that value. setting to the actual number of slides renders the thumbnail swiper un-scrollable. Thanks for your help. Really appreciated.

You can create an array in js to store the onclick event of the slider, along with some pop and stack functionality to take control over the sliders functionality.
Personally I would go with a bootstrap5 carousel and set wrap to "false", you can use the minimized version of bootstrap to save space.

Thanks for your answer. I initially had a horizontal sliding div with thumbnails. Given swiper supports thumbnails and the integration between slider and thumbnail is seamless, I am wondering if there is a way to overcome this issue.

using loop="false" is going to be your easiest solution to stop it from looping through all the slides. For any other custom functionality JS is going to be your go to.

nothing changes with loop="false". Ihave updated the pen
